# Cannot Record Payment to a Contribution in Pending Pay Later Status (WordPress 5.0.10, CIVICRM 5.21.2)

Tags: contributions, paylater

I was testing the Record Payment function in the following manner:

1. Click Contribution under Contact A
2. Click "Record Contrirbution"
3. Create Contribution, set Status to "Pending (Pay Later)"
4. Click "more" for the Contribution record, Select "Record Payment"
5. Select Payment Method (I chose Cash)
6. Click Record Payment

This will result in spinning of the logo and nothing happens.  This requires a refresh of the page to get out.  No payment was recorded to the contribution.

I have checked that this didn't happen to earlier versions (5.12).  Any insights?  Thanks.

Comment: can you check civicrm log for more details of the error?

Comment: Hello Pradeep,  I have enabled the dubugging and backtrace to test but there is no new logs entered in the ConfigAndLog. Thanks.

Comment: Can you open the record payment in a new tab and submit the payment?

Comment: When I open the record payment in new tab and submit, there is a HTTP 500 error. The URL that failed is xxx.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fpayment

Comment: Can you check php error log?

Comment: Hello Pradeep, thanks for your guidance, here is the PHP error and it led me to the solution: 
>
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bccomp() in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Payment.php:374 ... 


this prompted me to install bcmath: 

    sudo apt-get update -y 
    sudo apt-get install -y php7.2-bcmath 

restarted apache and the problem went away.

Comment: can add it as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your guidance, here is the PHP error and it led me to the solution:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bccomp() in
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Payment.php:374
..
```

this prompted me to install bcmath:

```
sudo apt-get update -y 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.2-bcmath
```

restarted apache and the problem went away.